# How to specify docker agent parametrically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins pipeline code we can set environment variables and use them later as parameters when executing different stages:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    MY_VAR = 'hello'
  }
  stage('Greetings') {
    steps {
      echo "Say $MY_VAR first"
      sh "./make-all-greetings"
      echo "This worked as expected!"          
    }
  }
}
```

This trick, however, doesn't seem to work when specifying a docker image as an agent:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    MY_VAR = 'hello'
    DOCKER_IMAGE = 'python:3'
  }
  stage('Greetings') {
    steps {
      echo "Say $MY_VAR first"
      sh "./make-all-greetings"
      echo "This worked as expected!"
    }
  }
  stage('Build in docker') {
    agent {
      image "$DOCKER_IMAGE"
      reuseNode true
    }
    steps {
      echo "Who cares... Pipeline breaks"
    }
  }
}
```

It fails miserably with:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: DOCKER_IMAGE for class: groovy.lang.Binding
  at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:284)
  ...
```

**UPDATE:**

Declaring `image "${env.DOCKER_IMAGE}"` does help with not breaking things immediately but the `agent` declaration section doesn't seem to see the same environment `steps` do:

```
[job-name] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . null

Error: No such object: null
[Pipeline] sh
[job-name] Running shell script
+ docker pull null
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for null, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

- Is what I'm trying to do illegal?
- If so, why?
- What are my options for parametric selection of docker agent?

Comment: Have you tried `${env.DOCKER_IMAGE}`?

Comment: @Vasan, yes, I have. It does not work either. Seems to return the environment variable as null and then fails when trying to find a docker container named "null". It seems like declaring agents happens on a different scope separate from everything else.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143675/6309

Answer (score 0):

Got it... Not sure I'm happy about it, but got it to work, just I wonder why it has to be so hard...

try :

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    MY_VAR = 'hello'
    DOCKER_IMAGE = 'python:3'
  }
  stage('Greetings') {
    steps {
      echo "Say $MY_VAR first"
      sh "./make-all-greetings"
      echo "This worked as expected!"
    }
  }
  stage('Build in docker') {
    agent {
      image '$DOCKER_IMAGE'
      reuseNode true
    }
    steps {
      echo "Who cares... Pipeline breaks"
    }
  }
}
```

Yes it's counter intuitive but the quotes made the trick.