# Jenkinsfile - agent matching multiple labels

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In my declarative pipeline, i need to select a node matching 2 labels. 
I tried something like this

`agent { label 'label1 && label2'}`

But i get an error that `there are no nodes`. I have a node with 2 labels `label1` and `label2` associated.

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
There are no nodes with the label ‘label1&&label2’
```

I know that i could temportailiy fix this by creating a 3rd label `label1-2` and associate it with agent in the pipeline.

Is there any proper way to fix this?

Comment: @KitKat, `agent { label 'label1 && label2'}` is correct. As pointed out by @Yap below, your own answer is misleading, since it matches any node that has _either_ of the labels. Please fix your answer to prevent others from being misled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok..figured it out.

```
agent {label "label1" && "label2"}
```

Comment: @VonC, hi, you are good at jenkins. Can you please help clarifying this for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772043/jenkinsfile-how-to-pass-parameters-for-all-the-stages

Comment: actually, correct is to use 'label1 && label2'  . with your approach, only any of the label was match, not both at same time. are you sure you have a node having both labels?