# Jenkinsfile: pass env from another script

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Consider a folder with two jenkins files, `JenkinsfileA` and `JenkinsfileB`.

```
# JenkinsfileA

node {
    environment {
        APP_NAME = 'APPLICATION_A'

    # Load the other jenkins file
    load `JenkinsfileB'
}
```

```
#JenkinsfileB

node{
   echo "Got parameter $APP_NAME"

    stage ('do something'){
       echo 'doing something'
    }

}
```

In B, the `$APP_NAME` param is coming up null.  What is the canonical way to pass `APP_NAME` parameter from A into B?  Should I be using `load` here or something else?  Are env vars. preferred or can we make use of `parameters` somehow?

### Update

I think the reason `env` isn't working for me is because jenkins is triggering second job in a completely separate workspace.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
load 'JenkinsfileB', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'MYPARAM', value: "some-value" ]]
```

But keep getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{parameters=[{$class=StringParameterValue, name=MYPARAM, value=some-value}]}, JenkinsfileB]
```

And when I try to use `build job` syntax instead of `load` the build can't even find JenkinsfileB, so I am stumped.

---

**Unreleated:** is `node` still the correct directive to use to ensure builds run on any agent, or should I be using `pipeline{ agent: any`}?  Got node from [this article](https://zwischenzugs.com/2017/04/23/things-i-wish-i-knew-before-using-jenkins-pipelines/)

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772043/jenkinsfile-how-to-pass-parameters-for-all-the-stages

Comment: Thanks Susan - let me see.  Do you happen to know the difference between `load` and `build job`?

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/

Comment: I can't really figure out how to use `build job` correctly.  I updated my answer.

Comment: You can't build a jenkinsfile directly and you also can't load a jenkinsfile with parameters. You can create a separated job that runs JenkinsfileB and then use the `build` step in JenkinsfileA to call that job.